# WP8 IMobileServiceTable - Detecting End of Asynchronous Call

Tags: azure, windows-phone-8, azure-mobile-services, asynchronous

My app makes a simple call the an Azure Webservice database and I want to copy the returned rows into a new list.

```
private IMobileServiceTable<dbEntry> entryTable = App.MobileService.GetTable<dbEntry>();
private MobileServiceCollectionView<dbEntry> currentEntries;

currentEntries = (entryTable.Where(ev => ev.event_date.Month == dateToShow.Month)
            .ToCollectionView());

foreach (dbEntry ev in currentEntries)
{
    //insert ev into another List
}
```

The problem is that the "where" call to the DB is asynchronous, so by the time the loop is reached there are no elements in `currentEntries` yet.

How can I detect that the call has completed before executing the loop? Is there an event handler for this?

Thank you.

Comment: Isn't it possible to use await on that entryTable.Where?

Comment: I rewrote the code and moved the DB call to an async method and used await on the call. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you found this solution already but I'll post it for anyone else that comes across this.

Unless you directly want to bind a UI element to the results of the operation, I suggest you do not use the ToCollectionView method. Instead, do the following:

```
private IMobileServiceTable<dbEntry> entryTable = App.MobileService.GetTable<dbEntry>();
private List<dbEntry> currentEntries;

currentEntries = await entryTable.Where(ev => ev.event_date.Month == dateToShow.Month)
   .ToListAsync();

foreach (dbEntry ev in currentEntries)
{
    //insert ev into another List
}
```